# WebClient error with Arrays VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, webclient

I'm using and array of files to be copied from a folder to another folder but it gives me an error.
`WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations.`

this is my code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    CopyBtn.Text = "Copy File"
    CopyBtn.Parent = Me
    ProgBar.Left = CopyBtn.Right
End Sub

Dim WithEvents CopyBtn As New Button
Dim ProgBar As New ProgressBar
Dim WithEvents FileCopier As New WebClient

Private Sub CopyBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CopyBtn.Click

    Dim src As String = "D:\test"
    Dim dest As String = "D:\test2"

    Dim filesToCopy As New ArrayList()
    For Each Dir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(src)
        Dim dirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Dir)
        If Not System.IO.File.Exists(dest & "\" & dirInfo.Name) Then
            filesToCopy.Add(dirInfo.Name)
        End If
    Next

    If filesToCopy.Count > 0 Then
        If MsgBox("There are new files found. Do you want to sync it now?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            For i = 0 To filesToCopy.Count - 1
                CopyBtn.Enabled = False
                ProgBar.Parent = Me
                FileCopier.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(src & "\" & filesToCopy(i)), dest & "\" & filesToCopy(i))
            Next
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("No new files to be copied")
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub FileCopier_DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles FileCopier.DownloadProgressChanged
    Dim bytesIn As Double = Double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString())
    Dim totalBytes As Double = Double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString())
    Dim percentage As Double = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100
    ProgBar.Value = Int32.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString())
End Sub
Private Sub FileCopier_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles FileCopier.DownloadFileCompleted
    ProgBar.Parent = Nothing
    CopyBtn.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

but when i put this code before the copying/downloadfileasync

`Dim FileCopier as WebClient = New Webclient`
it successfully copies. but the progressbar is not working,
even if i put this on`DownloadProgressChanged`
`ProgBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage` 
 it doesn't load. can you please help me? Just a newbie still learning here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wew, i just needed to add this
`AddHandler FileCopier.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf FileCopier_DownloadProgressChanged
AddHandler FileCopier.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf FileCopier_DownloadFileCompleted`

 with this codes:
`Dim FileCopier as WebClient = New Webclient`
`ProgBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage`